# Is it still possible for me to get into a master's program in a quantitative field?

Tags: mathematics, masters, career-path, statistics, economics

I am about to be a junior this Fall in college and I currently have a 2.6 GPA right now. I also don’t go to a very popular college and it’s located in the city. I have low grades and I am thinking about either getting into a masters program for applied statistics or maybe applied math. However, I might have no chance because I got a few C grades in my early math classes and I had to withdraw from Calculus 1 twice. I am also interested in economics and I have a B and B- in the first two economics classes so far. I understand that I screwed up bad but I am thinking about changing my life around. I have a total of 5 w grades and I am thinking about trying to at least get into a masters program for higher education as that I am thinking about pursuing a career in data science or possibly a consulting/financial field like quantitative analysis. I have a total of 5 w grades on my transcript so far and I don’t want to end up a failure. I just need brutal honesty. I am currently about to be a junior this Fall and if it’s not possible for me to get into a master’s program, what are some possible career choices for me? What else can I do? I don’t have internships yet but I am looking for some experience in the field so that I can get accepted later possibly. Are online master’s a good choice because I was just thinking about that. I also graduate in two years so does anyone have some advice for me?

Comment: Is this in the US? If not, where?

Comment: Your grades indicate something you want to pay attention to. Perhaps explore vocational school?

Comment: @Buzz, masters and doctoral admissions are very different.

Comment: Probably best to focus on what you can do to get your grades up. What's preventing you from doing better? Also think about what you want to do next...a master's program isn't a goal, it's a means to an end. What's the end game? What job do you want that needs a masters degree?